# changing the value of a select box by only having the xpath

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, code-injection, document.evaluate

I am currently using robotium to record a load of actions in an android web view. There is a known bug in robotium that doesnt let you change the value of a select box. in order to combat this when the test is running i am creating another javascript injection to change it. It works with name and Id but it needs to be able to use xpath as well in case a name or id arent available.

At the moment I can do this using the name and Id of the select box using:

selectBox = document.getElementById(identifyingValue);

or

selectBox = document.getElementByName(identifyingValue);

After this I can create a method to change the value of the select box the value that I want. The issue is that sometimes i cannot get the id or name of the select box and there isn't a similar method to do this via an Xpath ie:

selectBox = document.getElementByXpath(identifyingValue);

My code currently looks like this:

```
var selectBox;
var identifyingAttribute = ('$identifyingAttribute');
var identifyingValue = ('$identifyingValue');
var selectedIndex = '$selectedIndex';
if (identifyingAttribute === 'id') {
    selectBox = document.getElementById(identifyingValue);
} else if (identifyingAttribute === 'name') {
    selectBox = document.getElementByName(identifyingValue);
} else if (identifyingAttribute === 'xpath') {
    selectBox = document.getElementByXpath(identifyingValue);   
}
selectBox.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
if (selectBox.onchange) {
    selectBox.onchange();
}
```

So far you can see that I am trying to use the id and name first and the xpath as a last resort.

Is they a away that I can select an element by its Xpath and then change its value or perform a similar action. Any help or input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you aren't using jQuery, I strongly recommend it.

Comment: Why exactly would you be using xPath in a HTML document, couldn't you traverse the DOM in other ways ?

Comment: I am currently using robotium to record a load of actions in an android web view. There is a known bug in robotium that doesnt let you change the value of a select box. in order to combat this when the test is running i am creating another javascript injection to change it. It works with name and Id but it needs to be able to use xpath as well in case a name or id arent available. I'm trying isolate the problem into a smaller and more specific question sorry ><

Answer (score 0):

you can use **document.querySelector()** and select the property with a css selector.

documentation can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to the problem using document.evaluate()
The statement works for me:

```
selectBox = document.evaluate(identifyingValue, document, null , 9, null).singleNodeValue;
```